# Call master app's function with NC widget?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

how can I have my notification center today widget be able to call a function within my master app? I am trying to make an application that tracks when the device has activity by calling a function within the master app that logs an activity time in the core data.

code for logging the time and date

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
}
```

I'm willing to put any code in the NC widget for this to work

EDIT- Actually I figured out that all I need to do is share a xcdataobject between the two.

Comment: Actually I figured out that all I need to do is share a xcdataobject between the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to share code between your NC widget and master application, you need to put that code in a framework.  The framework will then need to be added to both the master application and the NC widget.

Comment: Actually I figured out that all I need to do is share a xcdataobject between the two.